# Create a 'post' object and initialize a m2m attribute with post id and author id

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to accomplish the following in Django:

An app that allows users to create image posts. They can view any post that is in the system and add those posts to their bookmarks. When a user creates a post, the post is automatically added to their bookmarks.

**Model**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id                  = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    post_image          = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to='images/content/', blank=False, null=False)
    author              = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='authors')
    tags                = TaggableManager(through=UUIDTaggedItem, help_text=_('Maximum of 5 tags allowed'))
    created             = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    bookmarks           = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='bookmarked', blank=True)
    bookmark_count      = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
    def get_create_date(self):
        return self.created.strftime("%B %Y")

    ordering = ['-created']
```

**View**

```
@login_required
def post_add_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {}
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostAddForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.author = user
            new_post.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            context['form'] = form
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Image uploaded successfuly!')
            return redirect('library:posts')
        context['form'] = form
        return render(request, 'library/post_add.html', context)
    else:
        form = PostAddForm()
        context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'library/post_add.html', context)
```

When a user creates a new post, that post will be associated with an additional attribute in the Post object called 'bookmarks'. The 'bookmarks' attribute has a many-to-many relationship with author and post.

I can easily create the post object, associate it with the author and save it to the db. That part is working fine. The part that I am struggling with is how to handle the 'bookmarks' field. The author id is easy, since I already have that from the session with `user = request.user`.

Somehow I need to obtain the newly created post id so that I can attach it to the 'bookmarks' field. This where I am stuck. I am new to Django and coding in general.

I have seen some possible ways to handle this, but I am not sure if they are correct or advisable.

**Django Signals**

I saw a few posts online about using signals.

**Django Transactions**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654790/create-object-only-if-other-object-is-successfully-created) SO post discusses using [transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly)

Do I need to use one of the above methods or is there another way of accomplishing what I want? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, all you need to do is add the user to the bookmarks field of the new_post. However, I think the new_post needs an id for this to be possible, although someone may correct me on that. By which I mean, the user needs to be added to the bookmarks after new_post has been saved (that's when new_post is assigned an id).
So something like:

```
....

if form.is_valid():
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.author = user
            new_post.save()
            new_post.bookmarks.add(user)
            form.save_m2m()
            ...
```